# EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/plain") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection Azure SignalR

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure-signalr

> EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/plain") that is not
>   "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection Azure SignalR

I am Getting the error continuously in MVC c# project, How to resolve the same

Answer (score -1):

On Startup.cs

`

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapAzureSignalR(this.GetType().FullName);
            app.Map("/EnableDetailedErrors", map =>
            {
                HubConfiguration hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                    EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
                };
                map.MapAzureSignalR(this.GetType().FullName, hubConfiguration);
                //map.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
```

`